# sympy equality test with complex rational functions gives None (unknown)

Tags: sympy, assumption

When an expression is a ratio with powers that I expect sympy (v1.12) to be able to cancel, I sometimes get results I don't understand. Here's an example. Notice that all of the symbols except `d` and `n` are real. (`d` is sometimes complex, and `n` is a positive integer.)

```
from sympy import *

a, b, c, x, y = symbols('a b c x y', real=True)
n = symbols('n', integer=True, positive=True)
```

I get what I expect for reals:

```
d = (a * x**n + b * x**(n-1) + c) / x**n
print(d.equals(a + b/x + c/x**n))
```

prints `True`.

*This* complex case gives what I expect:

```
d = (a * (x + I*y)**n + c)/(x + I*y)**n
print(d.equals(a + c/(x + I*y)**n))
```

prints `True`.

Same here:

```
d = (b * (x + I*y)**(n-1) + c)/(x + I*y)**n
print(d.equals(b/(x + I*y) + c/(x + I*y)**n))
```

prints `True`.

But not this case:

```
d = (a * (x + I*y)**n + b * (x + I*y)**(n-1) + c)/(x + I*y)**n
print(d.equals(a + b/(x + I*y) + c/(x + I*y)**n))
```

prints `None`.

The correct (?) answer seems obvious; I'm checking `d` against what I get when I cancel the `x+I*y` factors by hand. The `None` answer means sympy claims the answer is unknown, without further assumptions about the variables. What could make the result unknown, when the previous cases are not unknown?

Comment: The `None` just means that `.equals` could not resolve a definite answer. Returning `None` means that `.equals` makes no claim at all. In three-valued logic `None` is consistent with any possibility.

Comment: In this case `powsimp(expand(d - rhs))` works but `simplify(d - rhs)` does not which causes `.equals` to return `None`. I think that `simplify` could be improved to handle this case so it would be worth opening a SymPy issue on GitHub.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin - I see I my understanding of `None` was incorrect. About your `powsimp` comment, I'll look at opening a github issue.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/26086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The None answer means sympy claims the answer is unknown, without further assumptions about the variables.

According to my experience, it also returns None when SymPy is unable to verify the equality, for whatever reason.

```py
d = (a * (x + I*y)**n + b * (x + I*y)**(n-1) + c)/(x + I*y)**n
test = a + b/(x + I*y) + c/(x + I*y)**n
display(d, test)
```

[image]

This is a case where you might need to put in extra effort to verify it, by rewriting `LHS - RHS` (left-hand side, right-hand side) and verifying it is equal to 0.

```py
d - test
```

[image]

Now we expand it:

```py
(d - test).expand()
```

[image]

Note that the powers have not been simplified. Finally, we simplify it:

```py
(d - test).expand().simplify()
# out: 0
```

> What could make the result unknown, when the previous cases are not unknown?

My guess is that `equals` is not using `powsimp` in its code, or something similar in order to simplify powers.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to agree with Oscar Benjamin's comment. See my response to him.